# Should a non-document based app use an application modal dialog or sheet?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a single window based cocoa application. It does not have any documents etc. Essentially it is a utility app. I need to show a modal dialog box, basically a connection box to which has an ip, port, connect controls.

I read somewhere that modal dialogs are not recommended in cocoa based apps. Is that correct ? So should I use document based dialog ? I am quite confused about it, any guidance on that subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal dialogs can get lost in presentation (showing up on the wrong desktop/space, full screen issues, etc). Sheets tie into the window, so they always display properly.

Full guidance is available in the Human Interface Guidelines https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TP9

Comment: Even though  a program is not document based can I still use sheets ?

Comment: Correct. Sheets are not reserved for document based apps.